# Internet Explorer not launching , with selenium driver 3.11.0 and ie driver 3.11.1

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

*I am not able to launch IE with the configuration , IE Driver 3.11.1 and selenium 3.11.0.

This same code is working with Selenium WebDriver 3.6.0 , but fails for 3.7.0 and above.

Code:-

```
InternetExplorerOptions options=new InternetExplorerOptions();
                    //options.destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
                    options.ignoreZoomSettings();
                    options.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();

                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",ReadProperty.dictProjectVar.get("Driver")+"IEDriverServer.exe");                                                                                
                    if (Launcher.dicConfig.get("DistributedExecution").equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://"+ dicMachineIPs.get("Hub")+":4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());
                    }
                    else{
                        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);

                    }
```

Error thrown is :-

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: All firstMatch elements failed validation
>   Invalid capabilities in firstMatch element 0: unknown capability named ensureCleanSession
>   Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
>   System info: host: '5CG3455ZG9', ip: '10.4.5.242', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
>   Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
>   remote stacktrace:

Path of the driver is correct. 
Why am i not able to launch IE?

Comment: Because you spoke about **selenium 3.11.0** but your trace logs says **Build info: version: '3.9.1'**

Comment: Though downvoted by @JimEvans but the discussion contains important bytes from JimEvans - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895895/cant-launch-selenium-ie-driver-after-upgrading-to-version-3-9/48899810#48899810

Comment: I was checking with different selenium version thats why its 3.9.1 , but it is not working for 3.7.0 and above

Comment: **not working** doesn't throws any linght on whats wrong happening. Update the question with your current code trials and error stack trace.