# Selenium IEdriver issue "WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URLxxxx timed out after 60 seconds."

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, iedriverserver

I am using IEDriverServer 3.9 with IE 11 on Win10 . Test solution using C# with .NET frmaework 4.6.1.

I'm getting the classic error at the moment of lunching my selenium tests, it opens IE but after some time URL is not typed and the error comes up on the console "Selenium IEdriver issue "WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:16639/session timed out after 60 seconds.""

I have tried everything like swtiching the IEdriver to the 32 bits, adding more time and all with no luck. They randomly work if I restart the machine but it is very rare.

Example of my code

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            IgnoreZoomLevel = true,

            //EnablePersistentHover = true,
           // EnableNativeEvents = false,
            //EnsureCleanSession = true,
            //PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None,
            //FileUploadDialogTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30),
    };


        var webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

What can i do??

please help

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:16639/session timed out after 60 seconds.
```

...implies that the **IEDriverServer** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **InternetExplorer Browser** session.

It is a known issue as per the following references:

- [Can't launch Selenium IE Driver after upgrading to version 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895895/cant-launch-selenium-ie-driver-after-upgrading-to-version-3-9/48899810#48899810)
- [Selenium Java Client (v3.9.1) with IEDriverServer v3.9.0.0 (64-bit) crashes with org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28286](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5519)

This issue have been addressed through the following commit:

- [Properly initializing JSON values in IE driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/13d8f8be751001d44df8e5f1797518f4fb4dec6b)

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u171](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.12.0](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  current [IEDriverServer v3.12.0](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.