# Selenium Issue with Internet Explorer : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with xpath

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11, webdriverwait, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to run Selenium (*Selenium standalone server 3.141.59*) for my system in Internet Explorer (IE 11). It works till the login.

After the login it opens a new window and I use following line to open the desired page.

```
driver.get("http://appurl/function1.jsp");
```

After that I cant find any elements, not even by xpath as I get this error below.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element
> with xpath == //input[@value='Continue']

```
  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS);
    InternetExplorerOptions opt = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    opt.merge(cap);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\JavaProjects\\Test\\libs\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(opt);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

Can someone help me out on this? Thank you very much in advance.

---

### Update

I made following changes as suggested.

```
driver.get("http://appurl/function1.jsp");
// after login to system I navigate to the page in above URL
new WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue']"))).click();
// waiting for the button with value as 'Continue' to be clickable
```

But I found no success as the issues still remain.

I am also adding the log below.

```
RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.9.0.0
Listening on port 16289
Only local connections are allowed
Jan 25, 2021 4:07:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
FAILED: testLogintoImmunizationLive
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@value='Continue'] (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at com.immunization.IMMtestLogin.testLogintoImmunizationLive(IMMtestLogin.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //input[@value='Continue']
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'IT-PC-X', ip: 'IP_ADDRESS', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:16289/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss}
Session ID: 8e60910f-bfeb-4580-92bb-ddd8e7d06c84
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@value='Continue']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    ... 29 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to use wait function until continueInput element is clickable on DOM page. Code below;

```
continueInput = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@value='Continue']')))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. but the issue is still there

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to interact with just after `get()` so to `click()` on the desired element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[value='Continue']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233) in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, but it still didn't work. I updated the question above with the log

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.9.0.0
Listening on port 16289
Only local connections are allowed
Jan 25, 2021 4:07:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
FAILED: testLogintoImmunizationLive
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@value='Continue'] (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

...implies that the [IEDriverServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285722/what-is-the-correct-iedriverserver-version-to-use-with-ie-11-through-selenium/55286348#55286348) was unable to locate the desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) within the *WebBrowsing Session* i.e. *InternetExplorer Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though your *Selenium standalone server* version is **3.141.59** which is the latest released candidate.
- But your *InternetExplorerDriver* version is **3.9.0.0**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium standalone server v3.141.59* and *InternetExplorerDriver v3.9.0.0*. As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync you must use both the binaries from the same release.

---

### Additional Information

Further **InternetExplorerDriver server v3.9.0.0** had a known issue as per the following references:

- [Can't launch Selenium IE Driver after upgrading to version 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895895/cant-launch-selenium-ie-driver-after-upgrading-to-version-3-9/48899810#48899810)
- [Selenium Java Client (v3.9.1) with IEDriverServer v3.9.0.0 (64-bit) crashes with org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28286](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5519)

This issue have been addressed through the following commit:

- [Properly initializing JSON values in IE driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/13d8f8be751001d44df8e5f1797518f4fb4dec6b)

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  current levels [JDK 8u271](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  latest [IEDriverServer v3.150.1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.150/) level.

> **Note**: As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync and you must try to use both the binaries from the same **major** release.

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.